# C# - Sort dictionary based on Modified date and created date

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have some records in dictionary, I need to sort the data based on Created Date (CDate) and Modified Date(MDate). While creating the record, my CDate will have current datetime, but MDate will be 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

This is the sample data and code used for sorting.

***CDate                   MDate***
4/30/2013 4:43:41 PM   4/30/2013 4:46:47 PM
4/30/2013 4:43:28 PM   4/30/2013 4:46:36 PM
4/30/2013 4:43:54 PM   4/30/2013 4:46:16 PM
4/30/2013 5:03:13 PM   1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Code:

```
FileSchedulerEntities = FileSchedulerEntities
                       .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value.MDate)
                       .ThenByDescending(pair => pair.Value.CDate)
                       .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

As per sorting, I need sorted data in descending order like this.
***CDate                   MDate***
4/30/2013 5:03:13 PM   1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
4/30/2013 4:43:41 PM   4/30/2013 4:46:47 PM
4/30/2013 4:43:28 PM   4/30/2013 4:46:36 PM
4/30/2013 4:43:54 PM   4/30/2013 4:46:16 PM

But the aforementioned code is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: i think you cannot sort a dictionary. why don't you play around with `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Comment: @naveen - If dictionary is unsortable, Then what's the advantage of OrderByDescending() & ThenByDescending()?

Comment: @MidhunlalG: Please see the long comment on my answer. It answers this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of items in a dictionary is undefined as per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

If you need a structure that allows for O(1) access via a key, use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.
If you need an ordered structure, use something like `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

Comment: But I'm manually sorting the data. But the sorting is not working as expected.

Comment: @MidhunlalG: Because after the sorting, you are storing the data back into a dictionary, effectifly losing all sorting you just performed.

Comment: If dictionary is unsortable, Then what's the advantage of OrderByDescending() & ThenByDescending()?

Comment: I tried with this code also, without storing back to dictionary. `FileSchedulerEntities                                                .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value.MDate)             .ThenByDescending(pair => pair.Value.CDate);`.                    But no luck.

Comment: @MidhunlalG - if you want to *process* the items in the dictionary in a particular order, then you'd have the `OrderByDescending()` call as part of the source of your `foreach` loop, as an example.

Comment: @MidhunlalG: `OrderBy` and similarly named methods are *extension methods* on `IEnumerable<T>`. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. That's the reason why those extension methods are available on a dictionary. Calling them will result in an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` that is ordered the way you specified. So it makes sense that they are here. Your mistake is the call to `ToDictionary()`. This will create a dictionary out of the sorted enumerable. But this conversion is not lossles, because (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) a dictionary doesn't have a defined order of its items. In other words: Calling `ToDictionary()` on an ordered enumerable throws away that ordering.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Thanks for the above info. But this code is also not working.   `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, FileScheduler>> sorted = FileSchedulerEntities.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value.MDate).ThenByDescending(pair => pair.Value.CDate);`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Will my above code sort the data in an order such that,  whatever record is the recent record [Based on CDate or MDate], I need at the top of sorted array.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Thanks for the answers and comments. I got it. I understood it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f7fta44c.aspx).

You can create your own ToSortedDictionary<(this IEnumerable source, Func keySelector, Func elementSelector, IEqualityComparer comparer):

```
public static SortedDictionary<TKey, TElement> ToSortedDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }

    if (keySelector == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
    }

    if (elementSelector == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
    }

    var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        dictionary.Add(keySelector(local), elementSelector(local));
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: This answer misses a crucial point: This wouldn't retain the ordering created by `OrderBy` et al. It would order by what ever the comparer sees as the correct order.

Comment: Than it's an even more specialized dictionary you're looking for and you'll need to implement it yourself.

Comment: I thought the question was about the dictionary returned by ToDictionary not being ordered as you wanted.

Since it is how it is by design, you are now sure you have to implement it yourself.

Or is now the question "how to implement it?" If so, we need to know your requirements to help. Do you need sorting on the values or do you need sorting on the keys?

Comment: Paulo, I am not the person asking the question. I am the person that provided the accepted answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, Oops! My bad!